# Passing a variable as reference to javascript/jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called pages and i want to pass a variable selectively by not repeating the code again, is this possible?
old code

```
        <script>
        var pages= (function() { 
                    var config = {
                            $config1: $( '#block1'),
                            $config2: $( '#block-bottom1') 
                        };
                   //more codes
})();
        </script>
```

This was my attempt

```
     <script>
            var pages= (function(x) { 
                        alert(x);
                        var config = {
                                $config1: $( '#block'+x),
                                $config2: $( '#block-bottom'+x) 
                            };
                       //more codes
    })();
            </script>
```

Comment: I don’t see a function called `pages` anywhere. `pages` refers to the return value of that function. If anything, you need to pass something to the function in the `()` at the end of your code so that `x` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your problem is that your funcion **declaration** is wrong, you just made an **invocation** instead. Leave out the parenthesis and use your function as normal afterwards, here an snippet demonstrating the concept:

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <script>
     var pages= (function(x) { 
        alert(x);
        var config = {
           $config1: $( '#block'+x),
           $config2: $( '#block-bottom'+x) 
        };
                       //more codes
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="pages(1)"> button 1</input> 
    <input type="button" onclick="pages(2)"> button 2</input> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this:

```
<script>
    var pages = function(x) { 
        alert(x);
        var config = {
            $config1: $( '#block'+x),
            $config2: $( '#block-bottom'+x) 
        };
        //more codes
    };
    //Then you can call pages like this
    var a = pages("page1");
    var b = pages("page2");
</script>
```